# how to click a result from google search that is not on first page with selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to navigate through search results from google with selenium webdriver. I have a interface for user to inset word to search and site title to choose. If the result is not on the first page the driver should go to next page to look for the site, and if not there than to next page and so on..
Somehow I don't manage to get beyond the second page end if I did get to the second page and the right site is there, the driver doesn't click on it.
Here is some of the code in Java:

```
private void setLoopNum(int l){

        String getText = urlText.getText();
        String getSiteName = linkToChoose.getText();

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\selenium-2.44.0\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize(); //Maximize window
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
            //WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("http://google.com");
            //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
            element1.sendKeys(getText);
            element1.submit();
            //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS); //wait for page to load
                //try{
                boolean flag = false;
                String page_number = "1";
                while(! flag){
                //get all the search results 
                List<WebElement> linkElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h3[@class='r']/a"));

                for(WebElement eachResult: linkElements){
                    if(eachResult.getAttribute(getSiteName).equals(getSiteName)){           
                        eachResult.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='" + getSiteName + "']")).click();;
                        flag =true;
                    }else{
                        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='pnnext']/span")).click();
                        linkElements.clear(); //celean list
                        break;
                    }   //end else
                }
                }//end while loop
                //}catch(Exception e){
                //  System.out.println("Error!");
            //  }
        }
        driver.quit(); //clear memory

    }
```

Comment: Do you mean your code checks for result till 2 page only?

Comment: Yes, it goes only to second page if at all. never more than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things that you are missing in your code:
**Firstly**, in your code you are looking for only first element in your list.

**Secondly**, in getAttribute you are passing link instead of **href**:

```
if(eachResult.getAttribute(getSiteName).equals(getSiteName)){
```

it should be:

```
if(eachResult.getAttribute("href").equals(getSiteName)){
```

**Thirdly**, on clicking next the page is loaded via Google Ajax Api. Thus webdriver `click` will never block the execution of your code and will `load linkElements with previous page links only`. To avoid this let the driver get refreshed or put some wait for certain condition in your code.

Can u try out with this code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
while (!flag) {
    // get all the search results
    linkElements = wait
        .until(ExpectedConditions
            .presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By
                .xpath("//h3[@class='r']/a")));

    for (WebElement eachResult : linkElements) {
        if (eachResult.getAttribute("href").contains(getSiteName)) {
            eachResult.click();
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!flag) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='pnnext']/span[1]"))
            .click();
        pageNumber++;
        linkElements.clear(); // celean list
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions
            .textToBePresentInElementLocated(
                By.xpath("//td[@class='cur']"), pageNumber
                    + "")); // Checking whether page number is changed as expected.
    }
}// end while loop
```

**EDIT:**

```
List<WebElement> linkElements = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
ListIterator<WebElement> itr = null;
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
    "webdrivers/chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize(); // Maximize window
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://google.com");
WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
WebElement toClick = null;
element1.sendKeys(getText);
element1.submit();

// try{
int pageNumber = 1;
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
boolean flag = false;
while (!flag) {
    linkElements = wait.until(ExpectedConditions
        .presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By
            .xpath("//h3[@class='r']/a")));
    itr = linkElements.listIterator(); // re-initializing iterator
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        toClick = itr.next();
        if (toClick.getAttribute("href").contains(getSiteName)) {
            toClick.click();
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!flag) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='pnnext']/span[1]"))
            .click();
        pageNumber++;
        linkElements.clear(); // clean list
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(
            By.xpath("//td[@class='cur']"), pageNumber + ""));
    }
}
driver.quit(); // clear memory
}
```

Comment: Thanks,
Even this way the program goes only to 2nd page if it doesn't find the site. Also it finds only 1st element as it looks like only if first result is the right one it clicks it, if any other it's not. Maybe I need to convert the list to ArrayList and than go through it until it finds the right page...

Comment: Are you sure it goes to only second page? Cause when i posted this answer here i ran it 5 times with my expected link on 5th page and that too keeping the loop value to 3... :D N what do you mean by `convert list to ArrayList`?

Comment: It didn't go beyond the second page.
Even when expected result was on the third one.

Comment: It will be good if u upload your java files and share it with us...seems something hindering your environment...If u could share i can check in my local environment...

Comment: The file are in that link:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B28EZm6VHPq8R3BKQzlQcXpYVTA&usp=sharing

Comment: @Oren i have edited my answer. The thing that clipped your code was that your list was getting modified so a concurrent modification exception was preventing your code from further execution. Hope this helps now.

Comment: It would be great if you could mark this answer right... :D

Comment: I marked it now, hopefully it is the right one.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome buddy...but your problem was not specific to webdriver...it was java related...anyhow...happy coding...hv a grt yr ahead!!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're moving to the next page every time ANY of the WebElements in linkElements isn't what you're looking for. This will cause problems, as you need to relocate any elements that are re-rendered.

Give this a shot:

```
boolean found = false;
            int page_number = 1; //If you need this as a string, you can make it one later
            while(! found){
            //get all the search results 
            List<WebElement> linkElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h3[@class='r']/a"));

            for(WebElement result: linkElements){
                if(result.getAttribute("href").equals(getSiteName))
                {           
                    result.click();
                    found=true;
                    break;
                }
            }//End of foreach-loop
                if(!found){
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='pnnext']/span")).click();
                    page_number++;
                }
            }//End of while-loop
```

Also, you'll want to have some element-finding protection. Say that you search for something that has 0 results, or only one page of them (rare though that is). In the first case, you're lucky, because driver.findElements() should just return an empty list rather than throwing some exception, and the foreach loop just won't run, but in both cases, there won't be the anchor #pnnext, which will cause driver.findElement to throw an exception when you search for it. There are several ways to protect against this, such as writing a small wrapper function (IIRC, they have a simple implementation for findelementwithtimeoutwait() written on the Selenium website somewhere). I suggest you pick/write one and start using it, instead of the raw Selenium functions.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not do the job.
It get stuck on the first if statement: "if(eachResult.getAttribute(getSiteName).equals(getSiteName))"
Also it doesn't go to next page and sorry for asking that but the page_number has no use in your code.
:)

Comment: Edited my answer, I did not correct that you were passing the site name as the name of the attribute to evaluate. It should be href, since you want to be looking at the href to see if its value is the URL you want. It was likely returning null there, and then when you try evaluating if it's equal to your URL, it throws an exception.

As for the page_number, I took your variable and made it more practical. I didn't assume what you were going to use it for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,
but the search goes only to second page and not to the third or other than that.

Comment: I'll test it when I get home